# Is it possible to change the constructor method (__init__) name to something else in python?

Tags: python, oop, constructor, init

Can we change constructor method (`__init__`)  name to something else in python?
example

```
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0
    raise_amt = 1.04

    def __newconstructorname__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: You could probably do it by defining a custom metaclass.

Comment: Define a function and name it whatever you like, and then call it from `__init__()`.  I think that's the closest you're going to get unless you _really_ know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably to reassign it, but as @Barmar asked: "why would you want to do this?":

```
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0
    raise_amt = 1.04

    def __newconstructorname__(self, first, last, pay):
        print('in init')
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay

    __init__ = __newconstructorname__
```